# Page not loading because of lucia auth

Tags: authentication, prisma, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a registration page in Sveltekit using lucia auth.

The page shows 500 internal error if I add the below code in +page.server.ts

```
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    const session = await locals.validate()
    if (session) {
        throw redirect(302, "/")
    }
}
```

TypeError: locals.validate is not a function

Here is the complete code in +page.server.ts

```
import { auth } from "$lib/server/lucia"
import { fail, redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit"
import type { Actions, PageServerLoad } from "./$types"

// If the user exists, redirect authenticated users to the profile page.
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    const session = await locals.validate()
    if (session) {
        throw redirect(302, "/")
    }
}


export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const { name, username, password } = Object.fromEntries(
            await request.formData(),
        ) as Record<string, string>

        // check for empty values
        if (typeof username !== "string" || typeof password !== "string") {
            return fail(400);
        }

        try {
            const user = await auth.createUser({
                primaryKey: {
                    providerId: "username",
                    providerUserId: username,
                    password
                },
                attributes: {
                    name, username
                }
            });
            const session = await auth.createSession(user.userId);
            // locals.setSession(session);
        } catch {
            // username already in use
            return fail(400);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also declared lucia in app.d.ts

```
import type { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

declare global {

    namespace App {
        // interface Error {}
        // interface Locals {}
        interface Locals {
            validate: import("@lucia-auth/sveltekit").Validate;
            validateUser: import("@lucia-auth/sveltekit").ValidateUser;
            setSession: import("@lucia-auth/sveltekit").SetSession;
        }
        // interface PageData {}
        // interface Platform {}
    }
    var __prisma: PrismaClient

    /// <reference types="lucia-auth" />
    namespace Lucia {
        type Auth = import("$lib/server/lucia").Auth
        type UserAttributes = {
            username: string
            name: string
        }
    }

}

export {}
```

as well as in src/lib/server

```
// lib/server/lucia.ts
import lucia from "lucia-auth"
import prismaAdapter from "@lucia-auth/adapter-prisma"
import { dev } from "$app/environment"
import { prisma } from "$lib/server/prisma"

export const auth = lucia({
    adapter: prismaAdapter(prisma),
    env: dev ? "DEV" : "PROD",
    transformUserData: (userData) => {
        return {
            userId: userData.id,
            username: userData.username,
            name: userData.name,
        }
    },
})

export type Auth = typeof auth
```

Also, tried restarting the server.

Comment: Are you injecting the [handler](https://lucia-auth.com/sveltekit/start-here/getting-started#hooks) as per the documentation? It looks to me that you declared the types for your locals (`app.d.ts`) but you haven't inject them yet.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    const session = await locals.auth.validate()
    if (session) {
        throw redirect(302, "/")
    }
}
```

and update your app.d.ts

```
interface Locals {
        validate: import('@lucia-auth/sveltekit').Validate;
        validateUser: import('@lucia-auth/sveltekit').ValidateUser;
        setSession: import('@lucia-auth/sveltekit').SetSession;
        auth: import('lucia').AuthRequest;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).